# Apache redirects behind SSL terminating proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, http, redirect, https

I have the following redirects in the `<VirtualHost *:80>`:

```
RewriteRule ^/old-url$  /new-url  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/foo$      /bar      [R=301,L]
...
```

In front of apache I've got haproxy, listening on 80 and 443, the latter doing SSL termination and:

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

My problem with the redirects is that:

1. http://example.com/foo correctly redirects to http://example.com/bar
2. https://example.com/foo wrongly redirects to http://example.com/bar

How can I make sure `http` redirects to `http` and `https` to `https`? Note that I want to avoid having to write the redirect rules twice. How could I use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` or `X-Forwarded-Port` to redirect to the correct scheme?

Comment: when Apache acts as a reverse proxy in cases like this there is ProxyPassReverse, but since you use haproxy,  it surely may have something similar to respect the scheme the user sent originally, either that or fancy solutions from the Apache backend like the ones you've been provided already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the redirect will always contain the absolute URL, you'll need to make your redirections to be a full URL, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/foo" "%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}://%{HTTP_HOST}/bar" [R=301]
```

For this to work in all cases, you need to be sure that the X-Forwarded-Proto is always correct, so it should contain "http" for simple HTTP connections (I believe haproxy doesn't set it explicitly, so you'll need to do so). Also, the Apache server should receive a `Host:` header, so if haproxy calls the Apache server by IP, then you need to replace the `%{HTTP_HOST}` part with the actual hostname.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Note that you'll need to change `"${HTTP...` to `"%{HTTP...`.

Comment: Of course, the variable substitution character in Apache is `%`, not `$`. My bad, sorry, you know, habits and all... :)
I've edited the answer.